# c# Convert.To/FromBase64String confusion

Tags: c#, base64, binary-data, data-conversion

Assuming I have this Method.

```
private static void Example(string data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Initial : {0}", data);

        data = data.PadRight(data.Length + 1, '0'); 
        Console.WriteLine("Step 1 : {0}", data);

        data = data.PadRight(data.Length + 4 - data.Length % 4, '=');
        Console.WriteLine("Step 2 : {0}", data);

        byte[] byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(data);
        string newData = Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);
            Console.WriteLine("Step 3 : {0}", newData);
    }
```

I expect the output given the input string "1" to be as follows

```
Initial : 1
Step 1 : 10
Step 2 : 10==
Step 3 : 10==
```

Instead the output is this.

```
Initial : 1
Step 1 : 10
Step 2 : 10==
Step 3 : 1w==
```

And I have no idea why. I would expect the output to be the same as the input but it isn't.
I have tried replacing

```
data = data.PadRight(data.Length + 1, '0');
```

with

```
data = data + "0";
```

It appears with longer input strings too, for example strings with a length of 5 or 9. It works fine if I add "=" but then I exceed my padding limit with `Convert.FromBase64String()`

So my question is really what is going on and how can I get my expected output,?
What am ***I doing wrong***?

Edit: For those confused as to why I'm using bas64 it is related to this [PHP decrypting data with RSA Private Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25222881/php-decrypting-data-with-rsa-private-key-solved)

Comment: this sonuds like an ENCODING Issue

Comment: would this work for you
`string newData = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(byteArray);`

Comment: @DJKRAZE: No, absolutely not. This is nothing to do with that kind of encoding.

Comment: @DJKRAZE your suggestion resulted in `Step 3 : x`  But the thing is if the input is 2 characters long and I add 2 padding "=" then its fine. Also if I add multiple characters to the string that aren't padding then any added characters become "w"

Comment: @ThatHomelessGuy: What are you actually trying to *achieve*? You should be trying to encode *binary* data using base64... why would you take a string and pad it like this?

Comment: I'm padding the string because ¬Convert.FromBase64String¬ only works with strings that are divisible by 4 in length.

Comment: Garbage in, garbage out.  Each base64 character encodes 6 bits.  You are supplying 12 bits of data with "10", that's not a multiple of 8.  So it can only be decoded to a single byte, 0xd7.  Which is encoded as "1w==".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, there's no byte array which would be *encoded* to `10==`.

If a base64 string ends with `==`, that means that the final 4 characters only represent a single byte. So only the first character and the first 2 bits of the second character are relevant. Looking at the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) table, `10` means values of:

```
'1' = 53  '0' = 52
110101    110100
```

So that's encoding a byte of `1101 0111`, and then the final four bits (`0100`) are ignored. When you re-encode the data, it's using 0s for the final four bits instead, giving:

```
'1' = 53  'w' = 48
110101    110000
```

Fundamentally, it's not clear what you're trying to do - but if your input is *part* of a base64-encoded value, that's pretty odd. The code is behaving the way I'd expect it to - it's just not *useful* code...

Comment: I am using base64 as I am encrypting the bytes and the converting them to a hex string (for easy transport) then I am sending the hex string to a php script on a web-server which converts the hex into a binary string and decrypts them back before converting them to text again. Which all works up till the point of padding non uniform length inputs.

Comment: @ThatHomelessGuy: What does encryption and hex have to do with base64? If you're encrypting, the result of that encryption should be *binary* data, not text - so you can pass that binary data to `Convert.ToBase64String`. If you're expecting base64 to be encryption, it's simply not, and shouldn't be thought of as such. It's still not really clear what you're doing - you should show *all* the steps (what you've started with, where you're encrypting, every conversion basically) - and put that **in the question**. I've a sneaking suspicion you've just misunderstood the purpose of base64 though.

Comment: I am replacing the padding character with "/" 
I think I misunderstood base64 padding. Thanks.

Comment: @ThatHomelessGuy: That really doesn't explain anything... Again, please give more detail in the *question*.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25222881/php-decrypting-data-with-rsa-private-key-solved

Comment: @ThatHomelessGuy: Well that question assumes you're starting with a valid base64 string containing data to encrypt. Why are you accepting a base64 string rather than just a byte array? And why would you need to add padding yourself? What is the input to your `Encrypt` method? Because if it's *not* already a base64 string - if it's arbitrary text - then this is *not* the right approach. You should be using something like `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data)` instead.

Comment: I'll try that solution (I previously was using ¬Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(data)¬ ) but now I need to figure out how to convert from binary string to UTF8 in PHP. I was pointed at Base64 as it was apparently better for lossless data conversion with bytes as I previously encountered.

Comment: @ThatHomelessGuy: You use base64 for a lossless conversion *from* arbitrary binary data *to* text data. You use something like UTF-8 for a lossless conversion *from* arbitrary text data *to* binary data. It's really important to understand all the conversions you perform on your data - if you use an inappropriate one, you're almost bound to lose information. In PHP, I suspect you just want [`utf8_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php) by the way...

Comment: Thanks I'll go rebuild my authentication around the info you have given me. I am not very experienced with PHP and that very much reflects on how I interact with it. I got lost trying to compromise with PHP. Oh and thanks alot.

Comment: ¬Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data)¬ was the perfect solution and ¬utf8_decode¬ php side was the job. Again thanks.

Comment: After seeing what your answer is @Jon Skeet this makes total sense it was hard to determine from the OP's original question what he was truly trying to achieve.. I should have asked that question first