# NSString encryption with modulus & exponent values of a Public Key in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, encryption, public-key, modulus, exponent

I am quite new to Objective C development and came through the following problem:

I have the modulus and exponent values of a public key and need to encrypt an NSString value (password) with these values to pass it as a parameter in an API call. I tried to search the net but found no actual answer of how to do it. Can someone please help and post code if any?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this help you get started? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782327/converting-nsstring-into-uint8-t/4783258#4783258

Comment: What I need is like the answer of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497428/how-do-import-an-rsa-public-key-from-net-into-openssl but in Objective-C and not in C++....can someone help please?